# Twilio - How will twilio know which client to call

Tags: symfony, twilio, client, twilio-twiml

I'm using `Twilio` with `Symfony 5`, `ApiPlatform` and `reactjs`

I'm more looking for information than a response to a problem.

So I want to implement browser to browser call between two of my clients.

`Frontend` side, I have this function to initiate a connection with `Twilio`, which seems to be working fine

```
function createTwilioDevice()
{
    let device = Device.setup('some valid capability token');
      
    device.ready(function(device) {
      console.warn('DEVICE READY');
      const params = {To: 'Joey'}
      console.log('Calling ' + params.To + '...')
      device.connect(params)
    })

    device.error(function(err) {
      console.log('DEVICE ERROR : ' + err.message);
    })
}
```

In the `backend` I generate my `capability token` as shown in the docs:

```
public function generateCapabilityToken(string $clientName): string
{
    $capability = new ClientToken($this->twilioAccountSid, $this->twilioAuthToken);

    $capability->allowClientOutgoing(self::TWIML_APP_SID);
    $capability->allowClientIncoming($clientName);
    return $capability->generateToken();
}
```

I generate my `Twiml` like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/twilio/handle/twiml", name="twilio_handl_twiml")
 * @return Response
 */
public function generateTwiml(): Response
{
    $voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
    $number = htmlspecialchars($to);
    $dial = $voiceResponse->dial(null, array('callerId' => '+15017122661'));

    if (isset($to)) {
      $dial->client($number);
    } else {
      $voiceResponse->say('There has been an issue. Thanks for calling!');
    }

    return new Response(
            $voiceResponse->asXML(),
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['Content-type' => 'application/xml']
        );
}
```

After some tests the `capability token` and `Twiml` generation work properly.

So when I run `Device.connect()` in the front, this virtual device will connect to `Twilio` which will then call the url I have set up in my `Twiml` app which is `https://127.0.0.1:5467/twilio/handle/twiml` , from `generateTwiml()` just above.

The part I am having trouble understanding regards the client, how do I tell twilio to call this client or this client, given I want it to pass through the browser so no phone number?

Meaning I get I should pass to the function the client to call, but let's say I pass it the client lastName, `Twilio` will not know what client that is or what that string means

If anyone has any hints / doc / response regarding that subject I'd be gratefull, it's still kinda blury for me

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The Params are sent in as POST values to the VoiceURL defined in your TwiML app associated with the client access token.

Comment: yes but if I pass it the lastName of a customer for example, how will twilio know it should call this client?

Comment: If you pass an alphanumeric name, it can’t be a telephone number so you treat is as another client and construct the appropriate TwiML (Dial verb with Client noun). You just check to see what the client dialed.

Comment: Do you know of some doc abt it ? I think I see what you mean but are not sure how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: There is general TwiML Document for Programmable Voice here, TwiML™ for Programmable Voice - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml. This may help as well as well - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications. You can also look at other examples on CodeExchange - https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthToken is specifically provisioned to the AccoundSid and the devices' Identity.

When you generate your Twiml for an incoming/outgoing call and return it to Twilio, they will *know what client to call*, based on the generated AuthToken that is assigned to that device.

### *Note*

If you only want to dial the device, you have to set the identity of the device when returning the Twiml back to twilio. You also have to set the identity when you mint an auth token.

I recommend you set the Identity to your users' id from the db.
I also recommend you handle the token expiring.

Lastly, client to client is not free. BUT, P2P Video API with video off is. Think Teams or Discord.